# Change Dll loaded with MEF

Tags: mef

I'm using MEF and the System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll to load some dll.

I'm doing something like :

```
AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()), new DirectoryCatalog(directory));
_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
_container.ComposeParts(this);
```

to import my dll.

After some times, I would like to update my dll but if I try to delete it, I have an access denied, because it's alrealdy used by the program.

How can I release the dll, replace with a new dll and load the dll again ? (without closing the program)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable shadow copying in the AppDomain, this forces the application to behave similarly to a web app where the executable content is not running from the source location, but a temporary location.

The only problem you have is either

1. Use an obselete method `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyFiles()` which forces it on the the current domain.  Not advisable as this has been deprecated in favour of:
2. Use `AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";` when creating a **new** AppDomain.  You then need to defer execution of the your assembly in the other AppDomain.  Maybe this [form post](http://mef.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=73864) can help?

I'm not sure you can enable Shadow Copying through application configuration...

Comment: I've tryed many way, but unable to make it working. I had to make my application restard to have the opportunity to update dll :(

Answer (score 2):

If you try to insert on catalog one Object Assembly like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(directoryPath, ItemPlugin)));
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(assembly));
```

You can Delete\Change the file later...