# How to discover new MEF parts while the application is running?

Tags: c#, plugins, mef

I'm using MEF to load plugins in my app. Everything works, but I want new parts to be discovered when they are dropped into my app folder. Is this possible? DirectoryCatalog has a Changed event but I'm not sure how it works.

This is my code right now:

```
public sealed class RevealerFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<RevealerFactory> lazy = 
            new Lazy<RevealerFactory>(() => new RevealerFactory());

    public static RevealerFactory Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    private RevealerFactory()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    [ImportMany(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<IRevealer, IRevealerCapabilities>> Revealers { 
        get;
        set; 
    }

    public IRevealer GetRevealer(Uri uri)
    {
        return (from revealer in Revealers
                where uri.Host.Equals(revealer.Metadata.Host, 
                                      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                   && revealer.Value.IsRevelable(uri)
                select revealer.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) 
                                      + "/SDownloader/Revealers");
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to detect new DLLs being dropped in your plugin folder. Then you can handle such events by calling [`DirectoryCatalog.Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.refresh.aspx) or  [`AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.aggregatecatalog.aspx) to update the MEF composition with the new parts.

Some things to be aware of:

1. You need to mark your MEF imports as being designed to deal with recomposition, as explained in the MEF programming guide section on [Recomposition](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Recomposition&referringTitle=Guide). Otherwise MEF will raise an error when you try to update them.
2. `FileSystemWatcher` raises events on system thread pool threads (unless you make use of the [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject.aspx) property). Be aware that if you call `DirectoryCatalog.Refresh` from another thread, you must construct the `CompositionContainer` with the `isThreadSafeFlag` enabled. You'll also have to think about the thread safety of your property setters that will be called when the composition is updated.
3. You can also *remove* catalogs by taking them out of an `AggregateCatalog.Catalogs` collection. But there is no way to unload the associated assemblies (except by unloading the entire `Appdomain`). That also means you still can't delete or overwrite an assembly while the application is running.

Comment: in addition you may consider to enable shadow copying to allow hot swap of your assemblies

Comment: @tartakynov how to enable shadow copying?

Comment: @zionpi check out this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595304/change-dll-loaded-with-mef